# unable to install the IBM cognos Analytics

Tags: cognos

Actually I am trying to install the IBM Cognos analytics while installing it I was not able to see the license agreement to sign it and proceed to the next step. could anyone help me with this problem

Comment: What version?  (11.1.1 now has a separate installer that you will want to download)
Operating system?  What part of Cognos?  Framework manager?

Comment: version - 11.0.13 and windows operating system

Comment: Can you share the message or verbages of the last successful step and any message after that?